# Test_Input is redundant?

Tags: php

I know that I'm going to get severely voted down for this question which many of you experts will deem to be a lame question, but I am genuinely stumped on this issue. I have searched far and wide for what the PHP function test_input() does, but the available information on the web is incredibly scarce. My question is, why do you need a test_input function to validate user input when you are going to use preg_match in the very next line?? Preg_match is sufficient on its own. It's a self-contained function which does not need additional filters. So why preface preg_match with test_input? Isn't test_input redundant? But more to the point, HOW exactly does it sanitize user input?

```
if (empty($_POST["email"]))
{
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
}
else
{
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address syntax is valid
    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
    {
        $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
    }
}
```

Comment: We do not know what `test_input` does or why the author of this code felt the need to include it.

Comment: test_input() not a php inbuilt function i think you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21139420/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-test-input-in-c-wamp-www-web-new9

Comment: some w3schools manual/tutorial function

Comment: could be http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp
poor mans `filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL)` substitution it seems. - and then they wonder why w3schools got so a bad reputation.

Comment: @Rufinus If it's *that* `test_input` function, it's one of the worst pieces of code in the history of PHP on so many levels. And that's saying something. Jason12, don't bother wasting another braincell on this, it's crap, pure and simple.

Comment: deceze, you are very right. I've wasted too much time already on this mysterious, useless function.

Comment: @deceze: what i find especially funny is the example code on w3schools, beside the content of the function (which only suggest misplaced safty), defining the function BELOW the actual call is just BS

Comment: @Rufinus Personally, when writing quick-and-dirty console apps, I like to start `<?php main(); function main() { ... }` and define functions from there. But in general, yeah, not good XD